# Acumatica API - Appointment attachments

Tags: postman, acumatica

I am trying to attach a file to an appointment through the REST API. The example in the documentation is for the Stock Item entity which I can do successfully using POSTMAN. However, following the same process for an appointment is failing with

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

I am using the following URL for the PUT in POSTMAN.

```
{{baseUrl}}/Appointment/001234-1/files/image.png
```

I've also tried using the UUID of the appointment in place of the appointment number which gave the same error. This makes me suspect that the URL is incorrect. Here's a snip from Postman
[image: Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that Appointments need both identifies(PKs)

Example for invoices you need to use this:

`{{BaseUrl}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/Invoice/invoice/INV-067375/files/NewBitmapImage.jpg`

Just looking at appointments (DemoData) i am guessing it would be something like this:
[image]

`{{baseUrl}}/Appointment/MRO/006301-1/files/image.png`

Comment: Adding the service order type before the appointment number did the trick. How do you determine if an entity has 1 or 2 PKs?

Comment: hahaha trial and error. it was by luck I figured it out the first time